# Change the first auto reply on WhatsApp chat using Clickatell

Tags: whatsapp, clickatell

All the users receive auto reply message "hello" after they starts the chat on all our numbers. And this "hello" word is not exist in any auto response messages in Clickatell touch preference

Can anyone help me how to configure this "hello" message?

[image: WhatsApp hello message]